# creating quiz application in c# which randomly selects questions from a file

Tags: c#, random

i want to create a quiz application. the questions should be randomly selected from a word/text file(which contains some 20 questions). the application is in c#. syntax plz...

Comment: OK. That sounds like a good project. Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could go for sth like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153895/shuffle-lines-in-a-file-in-c/2153904#2153904) (except writing...)